# How to check if any words in a list of phrases are contained in a list in R?

Tags: r, string, match, vectorization, string-matching

I have a data frame with a column called listA, and a listB. I want to pull out only those rows in the data frame which match to an entry in listB, so I have:

```
newData <- mydata[mydata$listA %in% listB,]
```

However, some entries of listA are in the format "ABC /// DEF", where both ABC and DEF are possible entries in listB.
I want to pull out the rows of the data frame which have a listA for which any of the words match to an entry in listB. So if listB had "ABC" in it, that entry would be included in newData. I found the strsplit function, but things like

```
strsplit(mydata$listA," ") %in% listB
```

always returns FALSE, presumably because it's checking if the whole list returned by strsplit is an entry in listB.

Comment: Your attempts to solve this are decent, but you haven't provided a reproducible example, nor your desired output.

Comment: What about something like `mydata[any(unlist(strsplit(mydata$listA, " /// ")) %in% listB), ]`?

Comment: Thanks Alex, that has gotten me much closer. The problem now is that this evaluates over the whole listA, rather than one row at a time. unlist(strsplit(mydata$listA, " /// ")) returns all of the words in the whole list, so any() always returns TRUE.
Maybe some kind of apply function...

Comment: Yeah, I think that's because of `unlist`. Another possibility would be to check out `grepl`, though that is not vectorized over the pattern argument.

Comment: This may be overcomplicating it, but try `unlist(lapply(strsplit(mydata$listA, " /// "), function(x) any(x %in% listB)))` as the row subset condition.

Comment: **Use `stringi` package, specifically its awesome vectorized methods `stringi::stri_match_* / stri_locate_* `** or `stri_extract_*` for regexes. Also, you probably won't need to use an explicit split function, but if you do, avoid `base::strsplit()` and use `stringi::stri_split_*`

Comment: Alex, that solution worked! I am looking into smci's solution to help me learn what is out there in R though. Thank you both!

Answer (score 4):

1. `match(word_vector, target_vector)` allows both arguments to be vectors, which is what you want (note: that's vectors, not lists). In fact, `%in%` operator is a synonym for `match()`, as its help tells you.
2. But `stringi` package's methods `stri_match_*` may well directly do what you want, are all vectorized, and are way more performant than either `match()` or `strsplit()`:
   `stri_match_all          stri_match_all_regex    stri_match_first        stri_match_first_regex  stri_match_last         stri_match_last_regex`

Also, you probably won't need to use an explicit split function, but if you must, then use `stringi::stri_split_*()`, avoid `base::strsplit()`

**Note on performance:** avoid splitting strings like the plague in R whenever possible, it creates memory leaks via unnecessary conscells, as `gc()` will show you. That's yet another reason why `stringi` is very efficient.